# Rails: Added validation and now gettng error: undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am building an app with voting (a post has many votes, a user has many votes). It was working when I didn't limit the number of votes per user, but after adding a validation, it gets the following error when I try to vote up a post that the same user voted up previously:

```
>undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

>Extracted source (around line #28): 

>25: <% end %>  
>26:     
>27: <table class="posts" summary="User posts">  
>28:    <%= render @posts %>  
>29: </table>  

>Trace:
>app/views/posts/index.html.erb:28:in `_app_views_posts_index_html_erb__978098650233580665_2485618500'
>app/controllers/votes_controller.rb:23:in `create'
```

It works when voting for a post which the user has not voted up previously. How do I get rails to flash the error when the user has already voted for the post, but then redirect without an error? I'm sure I've just missed something obvious. The validation works when I try to add a vote through the rails console (ie, rails doesn't add the new vote to the database if that user has already voted for it). Thanks -

The related code in vote.rb:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :post_id
  validate :only_one_user_per_post

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true

private
  def only_one_user_per_post
    if Vote.where("user_id = ? AND post_id = ?", self.user_id, self.post_id).all.any?
      errors.add(:user_id, "Can only post once per post!")
    end
  end
end
```

the create from VotesController.rb

```
 def create
    @vote = Vote.new(params[:vote])
    post = params[:vote][:post_id]
    uid = params[:vote][:user_id] 
    if @vote.save
      flash[:success] = "You voted for the article"
      redirect_to root_path
   else
      flash[:failure] = "You did not vote"
      render 'posts/index'
    end
```

relevant code from index.html.erb:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="flash <%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>

<table class="posts" summary="User posts">
    <%= render @posts %>
</table>
```

And here's the relevant snippet from _post.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @vote do |f| %>
    <div class="right"> <%= image_submit_tag "plus32.png", :size => "16x16", :class => "squareicon" %>
        <span class="label success"><%= post.votes_count %></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your entire controller?  Looks like `@posts` hasn't been setup - it's nil.

Comment: That was the issue - I assigned `@posts = Post.popular` and it works. Didn't realize I had to assign it in the votes_controller as well as the posts_controller. Is there a way to keep the @posts from the posts_controller that was being used pre-vote (eg, Post.popular, Post.recent etc depending on what the user picked)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller, in the else-branch you have the following code:

```
else
  flash[:failure] = "You did not vote"
  render 'posts/index'
end
```

You also will need to retrieve the `@posts` there to alleviate the error. Or use `redirect_to posts_path` instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks `redirect_to posts_path` worked as well as assigning `@posts = Post.popular`etc. What would be the best way to have rails make a pop up alert and then return to the previous screen (similar to a `:confirm => 'You sure?'` when using delete in html erb)?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean, but I would suggest to use javascript. Either not go to the server at all, or render javascript (to be executed in the browser).